# Models inside tests - Django 1.7 issue

Tags: python, django, django-testing, django-1.7, django-migrations

I'm trying to port my project to use Django 1.7. Everything is fine except 1 thing. Models inside tests folders.

Django 1.7 new migrations run migrate  command internally. Before syncdb was ran. That means if a model is not included in migrations - it won't be populated to DB (and also to test DB). That's exactly what I'm experiencing right now.

What I do is:

In my `/app/tests/models.py` I have dummy model: `class TestBaseImage(BaseImage): pass`
All it does is to inherit from an *abstract* `BaseImage` model.

Then in tests I create instances of that dummy model to test it.

The problem is that it doesn't work any more. It's not included in migrations (that's obvious as I don't want to keep my test models in a production DB). Running my tests causes DB error saying that `table does not exist`. That makes sense as it's not included in migrations.

Is there any way to make it work with new migrations system? I can't find a way to "fix" that.

Code I use:

**app/tests/models.py**

```
from ..models import BaseImage


class TestBaseImage(BaseImage):
    """Dummy model just to test BaseImage abstract class"""
    pass
```

**app/models.py**

```
class BaseImage(models.Model):
    # ... fields ...
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

**factories:**

```
class BaseImageFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    """Factory class for Vessel model"""
    FACTORY_FOR = BaseImage
    ABSTRACT_FACTORY = True


class PortImageFactory(BaseImageFactory):
    FACTORY_FOR = PortImage
```

**example test:**

```
def get_model_field(model, field_name):
    """Returns field instance"""
    return model._meta.get_field_by_name(field_name)[0]


def test_owner_field(self):
    """Tests owner field"""
    field = get_model_field(BaseImage, "owner")

    self.assertIsInstance(field, models.ForeignKey)
    self.assertEqual(field.rel.to, get_user_model())
```

Comment: I have created a new model in tests & created instances of it, but i am not getting any error.

Comment: @ChillarAnand I've added some code. Did you do that using Django 1.7 and south switched off? I still get table does not exists :/

Comment: Shouldn't be your object mocked and not defined like that?

Comment: @aRkadeFR how would I mock that to make it work?

Answer (score 5):

There is a ticket requesting a way to do test-only models [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/7835)

As a workaround, you can decouple your tests.py and make it an app.

```
tests
|--migrations
|--__init__.py
|--models.py
|--tests.py
```

You will end up with something like this:

```
myapp
|-migrations
|-tests
|--migrations
|--__init__.py
|--models.py
|--tests.py
|-__init__.py
|-models.py
|-views.py
```

Then you should add it to your `INSTALLED_APPS`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'myapp',
    'myapp.tests',
)
```

You probably don't want to install `myapp.tests` in production, so you can keep separate settings files. Something like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    # ...
    'myapp',
)

try:
    from local_settings import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

Or better yet, create a test runner and install your tests there.

Last but not least, remember to run `python manage.py makemigrations`

Comment: This solution would cause the test model to exist as a table in the production database, right?  That is unacceptable.

Comment: No, the answer indicates to use separate settings files for test vs prod, to avoid the test model from being created in production.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a workaround that seems to work. Trick the migration framework into thinking that there are no migrations for your app. In `settings.py`:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    # Only during unittests...

    # myapp uses a test-only model, which won't be loaded if we only load
    # our real migration files, so point to a nonexistent one, which will make
    # the test runner fall back to 'syncdb' behavior.
    MIGRATION_MODULES = {
        'myapp': 'myapp.migrations_not_used_in_tests'
    }
```

I found the idea on the [first post in ths Django dev mailing list thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-developers/PWPj3etj3-U), and it's also currently being used in [Django itself](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/tests/runtests.py#L148-L154), but it may not work in future versions of Django where migrations are required and the "syncdb fallback" is removed.