# Django 1.7 makemigrations for test models

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, migration, django-1.7

I have a Django app with tests inside its tests folder. The tests have their own models.py too. How can I make migrations for the test model? Everything was working till I made migrations for the app itself. I think it expects to find migrations for the test model now.

App structure:

```
|______init__.py
|____migrations
| |____0001_initial.py
| |______init__.py
|____models.py
|____settings.py
|____tests
| |______init__.py
| |____models.py <---
| |____tests.py
```

Error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'test_db.mytestmodel' doesn't exist")
```

When running:

```
./manage.py test myapp
```

Comment: Why have code for tests outside tests.py? What's in models.py that your tests need to run correctly?

Comment: It is actually not my code. It is Django-tagging package that I'm trying to port to Django 1.7: https://github.com/seperman/django-tagging

Comment: possible duplicate of [Models inside tests - Django 1.7 issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25669290/models-inside-tests-django-1-7-issue)